# What is the correct PPA for Nemo?

Tags: nautilus, ppa, nemo

I have just changed my file manager in Ubuntu 20.04 from Nautilus to Nemo but the PPA (ppa:embrosyn/cinnamon) I have for it has an 404 error for one of the links in it and doesn't finish adding it in.
I was wondering if anybody knew the right PPA? I also reinstalled Nemo using Synaptic Package Manager so do I need a PPA at all or will that be alright?

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "correct PPA". PPA is a personal package archive created by some user. You install software from PPA's at your own risk.

If you installed `nemo` from Ubuntu official repositories, there is no reason to look for some PPA.

Comment: Cheers, I never do random PPA's but just thought there was one from who-ever made Nemo and I couldn't find it but if it's alright since I installed it from the official repositories than I'm all good now. Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

This add the repository Linux Mint uses.

```
echo "deb http://packages.linuxmint.com una main upstream import backport" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/linux-mint.list  
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A6616109451BBBF2
gpg --export A6616109451BBBF2 | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/linux-mint.gpg > /dev/null
sudo apt install nemo nemo-compare nemo-fileroller
```

You can also use

```
gpg --export --armor A6616109451BBBF2 | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/linux-mint.asc > /dev/null
```

instead of

```
gpg --export A6616109451BBBF2 | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/linux-mint.gpg > /dev/null
```